# Problems with exporting in Maya format

Tags: graphics3d, export

I am new in *Mathematica* and have a question. The forum holds some similar questions, but I don't find the solution for my problem. The problem is the following. 
When I create a vector field and use [`VectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html), I can't export it in Maya format without any problems:

> Export::nodta: [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)contains no data that can be exported to the Maya format.

Have you any idea? Is there a possibilty to export a vector field to Maya?

My code is the following (from [`VectorPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html)):

```
plot = VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "simple-vField.ma"}], plot, "Maya"]
```

Comment: Not all formats support all graphics primitives. I would experiment to try to figure out which primitives can be exported, and then try to construct the figure using only those. I would also try multiple 3D formats.  Sorry, I can't help beyond this ...

Comment: Some graphics primitives can be broken into (exportable) polygons using DiscretizeGraphics, but unfortunately that doesn't work for tubes/arrows.